# Replace text from an array using vb.net

Tags: arrays, vb.net, replace

How do you replace text from an array using vb.net?

In PHP it you would simply create an `array()` and use `str_replace()` like so

```
$str     = 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.';
$find    = array('Lorem', 'sit', 'elit');
$replace = str_replace($find, '', $str);
```

but how is it done using vb.net?

Im currently replacing like this:

```
With TextBox1
        : .Text = .Text.Replace("Lorem", "")
        : .Text = .Text.Replace("sit", "")
        : .Text = .Text.Replace("elit", "")
        : End With
```

but figured an array might be a better, faster, less resourceful option as everything that needs replacing is replaced with the same thing.

Comment: What array? A `string` is not an array. I'm not familiar with PHP anymore, so you might want to clarify your question.

Comment: @TimSchmelter: a string is most certainly an array.

Answer (score 2):

Write an extension method, like:

```
<Extension>
Public Function Replace(byval input As String, Byval replacement As String, ByVal find As String()) As String
  Dim result As String = input
  For Each item As String In find
    result = result.Replace(item, replacement)
  Next
  Return result
End Function
```

Or use a regex, like:

```
Dim value As String = "lorum ipsum dolar"
value = Regex.Replace(value, "lor|ip|do", String.Empty)
```

Or a combination of the two.